# Ontology inferencing

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I have a ontology design like below.

```
CompanyDashboard
 - ChaseDashboard
    hasBusiness some CreditCard (subclass)
 - AccentureDashboard
    hasBusiness some IT (subclass)
 - AxisBankDashboard
   - hasBusiness some RetailBanking (subclass)

FinanceCompany
 - hasBusiness some RetailBanking (equivalent)
 - hasBusiness some ConsumerBanking (equivalent)

ITCompany
 - hasBusiness some IT (equivalent)

Business
 - IT
 - FinanceBusiness
   - CreditCard
   - Banking (hasBusiness some (RetailBanking or ConsumerBanking)) (equivalent)
     - RetailBanking   
     - ConsumerBanking
```

When I do inferencing, 
For chase it does show that it is a FinanceCompany
but 
For Axis bank, it shows only Banking. I would like to show both Banking and FinanceCompany.

Comment: Do you intend that every thing that has some retailBanking also has some consumerBanking?  That's what your axioms imply.  Since (hasBusiness some RetailBanking) is equivalent to (hasBusiness some ConsumerBanking).  It's not possible, in this scheme, you have RetailBanking without also having ConsumerBanking (and vice versa).

Comment: You ontology structure really isn't clear from what you've posted here.  E.g., assuming that the Chase, Accenture, and AxisBank are individuals, it doesn't make sense to say "hasBusiness some CreditCard (subclass)".  You mean that those individuals *have* those types, right?  Not that they're somehow subclasses of them.

Comment: Thanks Joshua for response.
RetailBanking is different from ConsumerBanking. 
Should I have put has some predicate as Subclass for FinanceCompany class?

Comment: Chase, Accenture is kept as classes because I have dashboards for each of this company. May be my class naming is not good. Its like
`CompanyDashboard (subclasses - ChaseDashboard, AccentureDashboard)`
There will be multiple instances of this dashboard for different geographies and businesses. (updated main post)